# how to access generated groupname for asp radiobutton

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I need to access radiobutton groupname in my jquery.  However, groupname that's rendered for an asp radiobutton is kind of different.  Example:

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="payment" ID="creditcard" Checked="true" value="creditcard" />
```

will generate:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="creditcard" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$payment" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_creditcard">
```

I can't work with <%=creditcard.GroupName%> in jquery.  Is there a way I can get the generated groupname or name for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will get you the proper group name

```
$("#<%=creditccard.ClientID %>").attr("name");
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
$("input[name$=payment]")
```

This uses the [`$=` ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), finding names that end with payment, as long as you don't have multiple of these across containers, it'll work.

Alternatively, to be based on this specific control:

```
$("input[name=<%=creditccard.GroupName %>]")
```

Comment: thanks. the second option doesn't work because the generated name is not the groupname anymore for the element.
btw, do you know why the following doesn't work?

var paymentGroupName = $("#<%=creditcard.ClientID%>").attr("name");

$("input[name='" + paymentGroupName +"']")

Comment: @rap-uvic - That code works fine here, someone else outside that is interfering.

Comment: yes you're right it does work!  I was just messing up somewhere. thanks for your help.  Although I think I should mark Hunter's answer as the answer.  I hope that's ok with you. sorry.